# Listview inside Semanticzoom

Tags: listview, touch, winrt-xaml, semantic-zoom

I encounter a problem with using a ListView inside a SemanticZoom. It is hard to explain but I'am unable to "glue" my ListView to the left side.

When having the ListView inside the SemanticZoom you are able to move the ListView around with your finger. When you don't have the semantic zoom it will not move around and stay to the left.

Reproduction:

- Create a new Windows Store Application (In my case a Universal App)
- Create a SemanticZoom and whitin the ZoomedInView create a ListView with a bunch of ListViewItems
- Run and try to move the ListView around with your finger

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <SemanticZoom HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
            <ListView Width="600" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem>
                <ListViewItem>Hello World</ListViewItem>
            </ListView>
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
            <GridView />
        </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    </SemanticZoom>
</Grid>
```

When setting the ManipulationMode to "None" it will only move left to right but it will not stay to the left.

Thanks in advance,
Rick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this issue is a SemanticZoom problem. I found a solution on: http://poniaten.wordpress.com/2014/04/14/how-to-fix-scroll-in-semantic-zoom-zoom-out/

Quick: You need the following Style for the SemanticZoom:

```
            <Style TargetType="SemanticZoom">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode" Value="Enabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="SemanticZoom">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SemanticZoomStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ZoomInView">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ZoomedOutPresenter"/>
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="ZoomedInPresenter"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ZoomOutView">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ZoomedInPresenter"/>
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="ZoomedOutPresenter"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ZoomOutButtonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition From="ZoomOutButtonVisible" To="ZoomOutButtonHidden">
                                            <Storyboard BeginTime="0:0:3">
                                                <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ZoomOutButton"/>
                                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomOutButton">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                            <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
                                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </VisualTransition>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ZoomOutButtonVisible">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeInThemeAnimation TargetName="ZoomOutButton"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="ZoomOutButtonHidden">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <FadeOutThemeAnimation TargetName="ZoomOutButton"/>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible" Storyboard.TargetName="ZoomOutButton">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <x:Boolean>False</x:Boolean>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}" IsScrollInertiaEnabled="True" IsZoomChainingEnabled="True" IsZoomInertiaEnabled="False" IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}" MinZoomFactor="0.5" MaxZoomFactor="1.0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ZoomMode="Enabled">
                                <ScrollViewer.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                                        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ScrollViewer.Template>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderTransformOrigin="0, 0">
                                    <Border.RenderTransform>
                                        <CompositeTransform x:Name="ManipulatedElementTransform"/>
                                    </Border.RenderTransform>
                                    <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ZoomedInPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding ZoomedInView}" IsHitTestVisible="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="ZoomedInTransform"/>
                                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        </ContentPresenter>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ZoomedOutPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding ZoomedOutView}" IsHitTestVisible="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Visibility="Collapsed">
                                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                                <CompositeTransform x:Name="ZoomedOutTransform"/>
                                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                        </ContentPresenter>
                                    </Grid>
                                </Border>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <Button x:Name="ZoomOutButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsTabStop="False" Margin="0,0,7,24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Border x:Name="Root" BorderBrush="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonBorderThemeBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" Height="21" Width="21">
                                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="NormalStates">
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonPointerOverBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Glyph">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                        <Storyboard>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Root">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonPressedBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="Glyph">
                                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                        </Storyboard>
                                                    </VisualState>
                                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="Glyph" Foreground="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="{StaticResource SemanticZoomButtonFontSize}" FontFamily="{StaticResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0,0,0,1" Text="" UseLayoutRounding="False" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```